# jvm.stdout file not getting generated

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

We have a web service running on tomcat and we are facing an issue with `jvm.stdout` file getting created.
Sometimes file gets created and rolled over and sometimes no file is generated with updated logs.
Any pointers to debug this will be helpful.

Comment: I have a similar issue with tomcat7 stdout, not created sometimes.